# PHP fopen and pass variables to get variable value

Tags: php, variables, fopen

I'm Trying to create a License system for my simple CMS Script and I'm Using fopen function to do so but I got error.
Here is my code for my html form:

```
<form action="check.php" method="post">
<div><label id="Label1" for="domain">Domain : </label><input name="domain" type="text" /></div>
<div><label id="Label2" for="lis">Liscence : </label><input name="liscode" type="text" /></div>
<div><input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
</form>
```

And For The Form Action:

```
<?php
$dom = $_POST['domain'];
$lis = $_POST['liscode'];
$URL = "http://localhost/check/checklic.php?dom=".$dom."&lis=".$lis."";
$handle = fopen($URL, "r");
if ($accept = 0){
$letter = "Invalid License Key";
}
else
{
$letter = " Congratulation You Have Been License";
}
echo $letter;
?>
```

And My File To check the License with my database is:

```
<?php
$domain = $_GET['dom'];
$liskey = $_GET['lis'];
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "admin";
$db = "test";
$dblink = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
$mysql_liscode = "SELECT liscode FROM lis WHERE domain = '".$domain."'";
$query_liscode = $dblink->query($mysql_liscode) or die("failed!");
$liscode = $query_liscode->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $query_liscode->rowCount();
if ($count = 0){
$accept = 0;
}
elseif ($liscode['liscode'] != $liskey){
$accept = 0;
}
else{
$accept = 1;
}
?>
```

Note That The License Checker is in

```
http://localhost/check
```

And The Form with its Action is in

```
http://localhost/site
```

The Message is Always

```
Warning: fopen(http://localhost/check/checklic.php?dom=ammar.com&lis=1234) [function.fopen]:
failed to open stream: No error in C:\AppServ\www\site\check.php on line 5
Congratulation You Have Been Liscienced
```

Even If I inserted a wrong license information in the form

Any Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

change `if ($accept = 0){` to `if ($accept == 0){` and same for `$count`

Comment: the problem is not in the results the problem that is that the variables not passed I changed id and got the same result and the warning is still the same

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go out on a huge limb here and suggest the problem is the url,

Try it

```
$URL = "http://localhost/check/checklic.php?dom=".$dom."&lis=".$lis;
$handle = @fopen($URL, "r");
```